# При попытке запуска бота выдаёт ошибку "Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'". discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Когда я пытаюсь запустить дискорд бота (команда: node bot.js) выдаёт ошибку:

```
PS C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js> node bot.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\LehaH\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MineSuMi discord.js\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\BaseClient.js',
    'C:\\Users\\LehaH\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MineSuMi discord.js\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\LehaH\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MineSuMi discord.js\\bot.js'
  ]
}
```

Сам код:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Подключаем библиотеку discord.js
const robot = new Discord.Client(); // Объявляем, что robot - бот
const comms = require("./comms.js"); // Подключаем файл с командами для бота
const fs = require('fs'); // Подключаем родной модуль файловой системы node.js  
let config = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
let token = config.token; // «Вытаскиваем» из него токен
let prefix = config.prefix; // «Вытаскиваем» из него префикс

robot.on("ready", function() {
  /* При успешном запуске, в консоли появится сообщение «[Имя бота] запустился!» */
  console.log(robot.user.username + " запустился!");
});


robot.on('message', (msg) => { // Реагирование на сообщения
  if (msg.author.username != robot.user.username && msg.author.discriminator != robot.user.discriminator) {
    var comm = msg.content.trim() + " ";
    var comm_name = comm.slice(0, comm.indexOf(" "));
    var messArr = comm.split(" ");
    for (comm_count in comms.comms) {
      var comm2 = prefix + comms.comms[comm_count].name;
      if (comm2 == comm_name) {
        comms.comms[comm_count].out(robot, msg, messArr);
      }
    }
  }
});


robot.login(token); // Авторизация бота
```

Если что:

Node.js version: 12.18.1,
Библиотека для создания бота: discord.js

После обновления до node 16.9.0, выдаёт ошибку:

```
C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js>node bot.js
C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:489
      throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
      ^

TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:489:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LehaH\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\MineSuMi discord.js\bot.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'ClientMissingIntents'
}
```

В документации написано "Требуется Node.js 16.9.0 или новее."

Comment: Возможно ваш бот требует более высокой версии nodejs? Посмотрите зависимости данного пакета ну и попробуйте обновить node до более высокой версии

Comment: Обновил до 16.9.0, теперь другая ошибка:      throw new DiscordjsTypeError(ErrorCodes.ClientMissingIntents);
      ^

TypeError [ClientMissingIntents]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.

Comment: Обновите ваш вопрос, добавив полное описание ошибки, которое появилось после обновления. Так же посмотрите доку к боту, какие версии пакетов зависимостей должны быть у вас установлены.

Comment: Обновил, много искал в google, ответ не нашёл

Comment: [Похоже на вашу проблему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694195/how-do-i-fix-client-missing-intents-error)?